# how to split the string using the regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
Str="   $str='The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
              (a) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1) (b) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate. (c) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) (d) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.';
       ";
```

but I my desired outut is like this:-

```
   $str='The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
(a) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1) 

(b) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.

 (c) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) 

(d) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.';
```

I want to split the condition (a-z). How to use regular expression to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you recheck that the code you have given in the question is formatted as you would like? It's not entirely obvious if it's what you have intended it to be.

Comment: What language do you want to use to do that? PHP or Javascript?

Comment: people, $str is valid javascript variable name...

Comment: Possibly the most confusing question I've seen so far, the answers are for JS, the question now says PHP. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

For a set of characters you can use `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` for lower and upper case letters respectively. What you need is not simply letters, but to split `(<letter>)` (parentheses included). For this you may need `\([a-z]\)` (that is, to escape the brackets as they are so called metacharacters that separate expression groups).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
 str = "The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:(a)hello (b)asdadsdsa (c)asdadssad";
 $str = str.replace(/(\([a-z]+\))/ig, "<br/>$1");
 /*
 $str's value now is:
 The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
 <br/>(a)hello 
 <br/>(b)asdadsdsa 
 <br/>(c)asdadssad
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want, but using replace with a a regular expression should get you started:

```
$str.replace(/(\([a-z]+\))/ig, '\n$1');
```